# Section of indicator function in Sierpinski space

Tags: general-topology, logic, continuity

Let $X$ be a topological space and $S=\{0,1\}$ be the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), ie the topology on $\{0,1\}$ is given by $\{\emptyset,\{0,1\},\{1\}\}$.  Observe that the characteristic function $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$ of the open set $(0,\infty)$ is continuous for this topology.

Does it have a continuous section?  Ie: is there a continuous map $s:S\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\chi_{(0,\infty)}\circ s= 1_{S}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\chi \circ s)(2) \in \{0,1\}$ so cannot equal $1_{\Bbb R}(2)=2$.

**Edit** For the corrected question: no, as all maps from $S$ into $\Bbb R$ are constant, as $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, since I'm looking for a section, I meant to ask is there a map $s:S\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\chi_{(0,\infty)}\circ s =1_S$?

Comment: @James_T see update.